# double parenthesis require to ecmascript6

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

### Description

I have some code in `ecmascript5` that I want to switch to `ecmascript6`:

`var debug = require("debug")("express:server");`

I checked out some [examples](http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport):

```
import * as debug from "debug";
```

Is the closest thing I could figure out, but it completely leaves out `"express:server"`

### Question

How do I convert double parenthesis require to `ecmascript6` *in one line*?

Comment: You understand that *"double parenthesis require"* simply means calling the the function you import, right?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes and I was wondering if it was still possible to do that in one line rather than two lines.